# Bugs in canvas pixel manipulation in Opera

Tags: html, canvas, image-manipulation, opera

I'm learning HTML5 and when doing some basic things like canvas pixel manipulation, found out that Opera messes up the image completely when I want to change a color channel.
I've cooked up a small test page that should speak for itself: http://gda.0fees.net/tests/opera/canvas2.html (NB: the "expected result" images are dynamically loaded and the server is kind of slow).

The script takes the image and changes the red value for every pixel in a uniform manner. Here's the central point of my code (which you can see in full via the link above):

```
for (var i = 0, l = matrix.data.length; i < l; i += 4)
{
    matrix.data[i] += delta;
    if (matrix.data[i] > 255) matrix.data[i] = 255;
    if (matrix.data[i] < 0  ) matrix.data[i] = 0;
}
```

In Chrome, Firefox, IE 9, and Safari it works like a charm. In Opera, however, I get this result for both transformations: http://gda.0fees.net/tests/opera/opera.jpg

Am I doing something wrong? Is this a known bug? Can it be suppressed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I had to guess I'd say the red channel value was wrapping round to some invalid value. Note (in the source image) that the bugged areas are all much brighter overall than the areas that are properly treated.

It might be that its doing some sort of limit check, zeroing the red value of pixels where the original red value + 128 would exceed the maximum value used to represent colour components (a uint 8 maybe?).

I've never used HTML5's canvas before, but if you can sample the colour of each pixel, you might be able to suppress it by guessing the maximum value and checking to make sure you don't exceed it when augmenting that particular pixel's colour component.

**Try this:**

```
// Apologies, my JavaScript is very rusty, and this isn't how I would do this.
for (var i = 0, l = matrix.data.length; i < l; i += 4)
{
    var current_red = matrix.data[i];
    var new_red = 0;

    if((current_red + delta) > 255) new_red = 255;
    else if((current_red - delta) < 0) new_red = 0;
    else new_red = current_red + delta;
}

// What I would do is this:
for (var i = 0, l = matrix.data.length; i< l; i+=4)
{
    // I don't know if JS has a clamp function :D
    matrix.data[i] = clamp(matrix.data[i] + delta, 0, 255);
}
```

Comment: I do this: `if (matrix.data[i] > 255) matrix.data[i] = 255; if (matrix.data[i] < 0) matrix.data[i] = 0;`. Other browsers seem to do well with it. I should've put this in the question body, I'm sorry. I have added this bit to the issue description now.

Comment: I can't tell if this is just firefox being stupid and auto-correcting HTML, but it seems like you haven't closed an <img> properly, and also have a spurious </canvas> tag.

Comment: LOL, no, it's me failing at copypaste. Fixed (though the slow server may cache it for a while), but it doesn't improve the situation.

Comment: The other thing is you're adding before checking. What this means is, if you for example add 128 to 230, you might get 102.

By this point, your checks both report OK, so nothing is done.

What you should check is that the current value +- the delta does not exceed 255, or drop below 0.

Comment: You're a genius and I'm an idiot! This is exactly what's been happening - apparently Opera is the only browser that uses one-byte capping right after the calculation, and not during drawing. Now it works perfectly, thanks a million!!

Comment: You're welcome, but don't count yourself out. I do stupid stuff like that all the time. Its one of these little gotchas that you pick up programming shaders (and is the exact sort of bug that is responsible for some of the most interesting shaders :)).